# How can I save my data when using tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have the following code:

```
<textarea cols=100 rows=15 style="width: 825px;" 
                        class="mceEditor"
                        id="Text" 
                        name="Text">@Model.Text</textarea>
```

When my code runs I do tinyMCE.init and this creates the following HTML:

```
<textarea name="Text" id="mce_43" class="mceEditor wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="width: 825px; display: none;" rows="15" cols="100" aria-hidden="true"><p>test data</p></textarea>
```

followed by code for the tinyMCE window with the correct text in the window.

But when I make a change to the data and click submit on the form then the original data is returned and nothing of the data that I changed in the tinyMCE window is stored.

Is there something else I need to do to have the data from the window stored?

Comment: Do you use a standard 'submit' button of the form or your own js code which gathers all information and submits it to the server?

Comment: Just pass the value to viewmodel and save.You can get more from here http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget

Answer (score 1):

Try `tinyMCE.triggerSave()` before sending data.